# How to solve "Could not find artifact javax.xml.ws:WebServiceContext" error when launching application with maven?

Tags: java, maven

I am following [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43574426/how-to-resolve-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-xml-bind-jaxbexception-in-j) to build an application named [Entando][2].

Particularly I did the steps in 2.2 using the `maven` command to build the application

```
mvn archetype:generate -Dfilter=entando-archetype-webapp-generic
```

and it was successful.

Then to launch the application there is written to use the `maven` command

```
mvn clean jetty:run
```

At first I had the error described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43574426/how-to-resolve-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-xml-bind-jaxbexception-in-j) but solved thanks to the answer there.

Now I am getting a similar error for `javax.xml.ws:WebServiceContext`:

I tried to modify the `pom.xml` file by adding:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.ws</groupId>
    <artifactId>WebServiceContext</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.11</version>
</dependency>
```

but it did not work resulting in the error:

```
Could not find artifact javax.xml.ws:WebServiceContext:jar:1.1.1 in snapshot-repository (https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/)
```

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution, I will share it in case someone will need it:

In the `pom.xml` I added:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxws-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.6</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to add this javax.xml.ws dependency if you are using JDK 1.8 its rt.java already include this. If your JDK do not have rt.java ,just reconfigure it in your eclipse.

Comment: if you have a proprietary or broken JDK installation while building/executing then this is your answer

Answer (score 0):

Add this dependency in your project-

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxws-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.6</version>
    </dependency>
```

and mvn clean install